# Is this symbol used enough to have a name?

Tags: notation

I'm not sure how to type it, so here's an image drawn using MS Paint:

[image]

It's an equals sign and a question mark superimposed on each other. From the times I've seen the symbol, it asks if the LHS is equal to the RHS. If yes, then [do something]. If not, then [do something else]. For example,

```
a =? b

If yes, then the proof is complete. If not, then we must have b < c ... [yada yada blah blah]
```

This symbol is not on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glossary_of_mathematical_symbols), so I'm guessing it's nonstandard. If it is indeed nonstandard, then what is the most common way of expressing `a =? b`?

Comment: You'll find some answers [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/387681/align-on-equal-sign-when-using-stackrel-by-defining-a-single-command). So for example $a \overset{?}{=}b$. I use it often as $a \overset{(1)}{=}b$, which says that I have used $(1)$ to derive that $a=b$.

Comment: The most common way, however, would be to say:" We need to check whether or not $a=b$. Then the proof is correct."